# Windows 7 showing fake/aliased drives

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, partitioning, disk-management

Some years back I used a tool (sorry, can't remember the name) to migrate a Windows 7 install off a spinning drive to a new SSD. I think the old drive had two partitions, one for the system and one I had for just storing files.

Anyway, this process left me with a Windows 7 that shows *4* drives when viewing Computer.

- `C:` This is the new SDD I'm booting off
- `D:` The data partition of the spinning drive (I still use this from time to time)
- `E:` A drive identical in size and usage to `C:`. I put a file on `C:` and it shows up under `E:` as well. I never dared touching this.
- `G:` What I assume is the old system partition. I never really dared touching this.

What I'd like to do is:

- Get rid of `E:`, but I don't know how. I googled around a bit and people with similar problems seemed to have had it caused by `subst`, but this is not the case as the `subst` command lists nothing for me.
- Get rid of `G:` and if possible extend `D:` to use the freed up space. This does make me a bit scared though, since when I was uninstalling an old program recently it said it was removing files from `G:`. No idea what that was about. Is there any way to try to boot the system with this partition disabled first to see if removing it would cause any problems?

**Edit:**
This is what things look like in Explorer:

[image]

And this is what things look like under Disk Management:

[image]

So, `C:` looks fine, `D:` and `G:` looks fine in the graphic view, but the size of `D:` is the size of the entire drive in the list view. `E:` is missing entirely and it's also showing an unlabeled volume.

**Edit:**
I think the unlabeled drive might be the result of my BIOS lying to the OS about some long gone drive. I need to investigate this further but I feel this is outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open **Windows Explorer**
2. Right-click on **Computer** then **Manage**
3. Open **Disk Management**

From that window:

1. To completely remove a partition:

   1. Right-click the partition
   2. Click Delete (may be greyed out if system-critical)
2. To remove an alias:

   1. Right-click the partition
   2. Click **Modify volume letter and paths**
   3. Change at will
3. More options from right-click menu (including "Expand partition")

Comment: Removing the `G:` partition turned my `E:` drive into an "Other" drive (with a blue question mark). I accept your answer as a solution as it did help me get rid of `G:` and I feel that the question now has morphed into something else.